# Slide to Unlock Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, textview

I want to create the "slide to unlock" animation that is found on iPhones, on my Android application. Basically have a running wave-like color animation through a textview. Any ideas?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android

Information on how to use it is in the wiki.

**But for the sake of completion:**

Add a ShimmerTextView to your layout:

```
<com.romainpiel.shimmer.ShimmerTextView
    android:id="@+id/shimmer_tv"
    android:text="@string/shimmer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#444"
    android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

To start the animation:

```
shimmer = new Shimmer();
shimmer.start(myShimmerTextView);
```

You may want to keep track of the shimmer instance after the animation is started if you want to stop it.

To stop it:

```
shimmer.cancel();
```

**Enjoy** :D